# How to change the chrome extension image in chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to set the featured image of a chrome extension in the web store like in the link below:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/color%20eyedropper

Is this done via the manifest.json?

Comment: It's automatically set from your promo image, might take some time on their servers. You can find several detailed answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have set a promo image under the "promotional tile images" but still the image reflected on the web store is the "icon" required by the extension.

Comment: yes will do. thanks @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the images needed in the zip file of your app. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images

For setting a promotional image, this can be done through the [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).